# Returning Http Error Status from catch block in MVC Controller.OnActionExecuting seems to cause Empty Result to be returned to HTTP request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-mvc-5

I've worked to make my case very simple.

MVC 5 ASP.NET application.

I have a the following controller:

```
public class SampleController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult ShowTicket()
    {
        return Content($"Ticket is {Session["SessionTicket"]}");
    }
}
```

And here is one version of my base controller that works as I expect it to:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request; // Could also get from static HttpContext, but I think this one is correct.

        string sessionTicket = request.QueryString["sessionTicket"] ?? request.Form["sessionTicket"] ?? request.Headers["sessionTicket"];

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sessionTicket))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "No session ticket specified");
        }

        Session["SessionTicket"] = sessionTicket;
    }
}
```

In this case, if I navigate to my Url, namely https://localhost:44329/Sample/ShowTicket?sessionTicket=foo , I am indeed presented with the message "Ticket is foo".  Instead, if leave the sessionTicket out of the query string (and it isn't in the form or the header either), then I will get as expected an HTTP 400 Bad Request error, with the message that states no session ticket was specified.  All good.  I'm happy, Fiddler is happy, browser shows sensible results.

However, if now replace my base controller with the following:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request; // Could also get from static HttpContext, but I think this one is correct.

        string sessionTicket = request.QueryString["sessionTicket"] ?? request.Form["sessionTicket"] ?? request.Headers["sessionTicket"];

        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sessionTicket))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sessionTicket), "No session ticket specified");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message);
        }

        Session["SessionTicket"] = sessionTicket;
    }
}
```

My expectation is that this would function almost exactly the same.  But it doesn't.  The positive case (where "sessionTicket" is specified) does in fact behave identically.  But the negative case where I leave the session Ticket out of the query string (hoping to generate an HTTP Bad Request) does not generate the Bad Request.  It seems to merely return a completely empty response (not even headers) such that the browser interprets it as if the connection was reset.  Fiddler can't find any response.

Because of the architecture of my larger application, I do actually want to effect this in the catch block.  What am I doing wrong?  And how is this mystery explained?

Many thanks.

Comment: are you using HandleError of have an ExceptionFilter in your project?

Comment: Neither HandleError nor ExceptionFilter are referenced in any way in the project.  This was simply scaffolded by Visual Studio as an empty MVC 5 project.  There isn't really much in it other than what you see in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that I was trying to set the message of an HttpStatusCodeResult to a string that had newlines in it.  Apparently this causes MVC to choke.  If the string doesn't have newlines, then it works fine.  The catch block is not the problem.

To me it seems like the MVC failure in this case is pretty ungraceful... but perhaps that is just opinion!